# Ansible Error: local variable 'value' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, json, ansible, indentation, ansi

When trying to retrieve some of the fields of a `JSON`, `ansible` throws this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'value' referenced before assignment
```

The structure, fields' name, and indentation of the `JSON` do not seem to be the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the special `space` characters that were used in the source file of the `JSON`. After converting to ANSI, they appeared as `Â` . After replacing them with the regular `space` characters, the error message disappeared.